# x-editable plugin compatibility with bootstrap 3 and bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap 3 and [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/), i tried to use [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) plugin to make cells editable. When I use 'popup' mode and want to edit a cell, there is shown another empty cell next to the cell. I am not sure if it a bug or not.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/14/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="name" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
    <th data-field="stargazers_count" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Stars</th>
    <th data-field="forks_count" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Forks</th>
    <th data-field="description" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

**JS**

```
var data = [{name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"}]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
});

$('table tbody tr td').editable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use this bootstrap-table-editable extension: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/editable

Here is a working example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/

Edit:

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/22/)

Three things:

- Add the bootstrap-table-editable extension to the scripts
- Add the attribute `data-editable="true"` to each column
- Remove the JavaScript code: `$('table tbody tr td').editable();` because it's not needed

Check this page for other extensions: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/

Comment: Look at my jsfiddle, I use this extension which needs x-editable plugin.